# Angular 4 : How to get index of selected value in a datalist

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I use a reactive form. In a list of items (comes from the database), the user can select an item according to several criteria : either by reference number, name, manufacturer name...

If user chooses by reference number, will be displayed an input list with list of reference number from the *listOfItems*, if he chooses by name, will be displayed an input list with list of name from the *listOfItems*, etc...

For example, when a user select an item by name in the datalist and validate, I want to send and display it in another component with its characteristics. So, to know which item has been selected and to have access all its characteristics, I need to get index of selected item in the datalist.

**component.html** (item selected by name) :

```
<div *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection.controls.radioBoutton.value==='itemName'">
    <input list="itemsName" formControlName="itemNameSelected" type="text" name="itemNameSelected">
    <datalist id="itemsName">
      <option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems">{{ref.itemDesignation.input}}</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>
```

In the **component.ts**, in can access to inputs user value with :

```
this.valueSelected = this.formGroupItemSelection.controls.itemNameSelected.value
```

But how to get index ?

**--UPDATE--**
I tried to add *"[(ngModel)]='itemSelected'"* in my input list :

```
<div *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection.controls.radioBoutton.value==='itemName'">
    <input list="itemsName" id="itemsName" formControlName="itemNameSelected" type="text" name="itemNameSelected" [(ngModel)]="itemSelected">
    <datalist id="itemsName">
        <option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems" [ngValue]="ref" >{{ref.itemDesignation.input}}
        </option>
</datalist>
```

And then call in the console of my **component.ts** *"itemSelected"*, but it doesn't take the value of *"ref"* :

```
addItem() {
    console.log(this.itemSelected);
}
```

I looked in several subjects and I didn't find the solution, it seems that the problem comes from the datalist...

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection.controls.radioBoutton.value==='itemName'">
    <input list="itemsName" formControlName="itemNameSelected" type="text" name="itemNameSelected">
    <datalist id="itemsName">
      <option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems;let i = index" [ngValue]="i">{{ref.itemDesignation.input}}</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>
```

Comment: And how to get it in the component.ts ?

Comment: Can you help me to bind them ? @Chellappan

Comment: For example, I added "[(ngModel)]="itemSelected" to my input list and then call in the console of my component.ts "itemSelected", but it doesn't take the value of "i"

Comment: yes i saw since you using datalist whatever you selecting will be  inside innerHTML that is why it is diffcult to get the id

Comment: So Are there no other ways to circuvment this ? I really need the datalist to do a filtered search unlike the select.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `findIndex` function

```
let idx = listOfItems.findIndex((item) => item.itemDesignation.input === this.valueSelected)
```

This will iterate the `listOfItems` array until it finds one where its `itemDesignation.input` matches `this.valueSelected`

Comment: I can't do that because two items may have the same name

Answer (score 0):

Take `<option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems">`

And change it to `<option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems;let i = index">`

Now you can reference the variable {{i}} to get the index.

EDIT: Showing you how you can view `i` in your component.

HTML:

```
<datalist ...>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems; let i = index">
        <option (click)="funtionThatNeedsIndex(i)">{{ref.itemDesignation.input}}</option>
    </ng-container>
</datalist>
```

Component.ts :

```
functionThatNeedsIndex(index) {
    console.log(index);
}
```

Comment: I will have index of all items in the datalist but i need index of the selected value. How to get it in the component.ts ?

Comment: Read @Chellappan's answer. He shows how you can bind the {{i}} to the selected value in the list.

Comment: @Josept When you set the `ngModel` to `{{ i }}`, that should be the value getting stored as the users choice, instead of the actual text of the entry.

Comment: @Josept I've put an edit in my answer, try copy pasting it and seeing if the function `functionThatNeedsIndex` gets called when you select an item from the dropdown.

Comment: No, that's not called i don't see anything displayed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Take `<option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems">`

And change it to `<option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems;let i = index">`

Add a click event that sends the templatevariable + index, add that method to your component. Now when the user clicks on an option, it will send to the component.

```
<div *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection.controls.radioBoutton.value==='itemName'">
        <input list="itemsName" formControlName="itemNameSelected" type="text" name="itemNameSelected">
        <datalist id="itemsName">
          <option #selectedOption *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems; let i = index" (click)="selectedOption(i,selectedOption)">{{ref.itemDesignation.input}}</option>
        </datalist>
      </div>
```